# Effectiveness of Mathematica to solve Hamilton Circuits

Tags: graphs-and-networks, mathematical-optimization

Has anyone ever tried Mathematica to solve instances of this data set: http://fhcp.edu.au/fhcpcs

Mind sharing your results?

Comment: Perhaps you can also show what you have already tried in Mathematica ? This could be helpful for others in answering your question

Comment: You might find the function FindHamiltonianCycle to be useful. It's built into the language.